# Emulating ARM v8 to run DietPi in qemu for userspace software

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu

I can't seem to get [DietPi](https://dietpi.com/) to boot on a generic ARM 64 bit `virt` machine in [qemu](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM). I'm using the Raspberry Pi ARMv8 64-bit DietPi image (for Raspberry Pi 4).

What am I missing/need to change to get DietPi running in emulation for userspace software development?

I've extracted the kernel, device tree, and command line.
The `/etc/fstab` of the image uses partition UUIDs:

```
$ cat /mnt/rpi/etc/fstab 
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# TMPFS
#----------------------------------------------------------------
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs noatime,lazytime,nodev,nosuid,mode=1777
tmpfs /var/log tmpfs size=50M,noatime,lazytime,nodev,nosuid,mode=1777
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# PHYSICAL DRIVES
#----------------------------------------------------------------
PARTUUID=df909cde-02 / ext4 noatime,lazytime,rw 0 1
PARTUUID=df909cde-01 /boot vfat noatime,lazytime,rw 0 2
```

The `cmdline.txt` that comes with DietPi is:

```
root=PARTUUID=df909cde-02 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fsck.repair=yes net.ifnames=0 logo.nologo console=serial0,115200 console=tty1
```

The furthest I've gotten in the boot process has been this `qemu-system-aarch64` invocation, which ends up hanging at `Waiting for root device PARTUUID...`:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M virt \
    -cpu cortex-a72 \
    -m 256 \
    -kernel kernel8.img \
    -drive file=DietPi_RPi-ARMv8-Bullseye.img \
    -append "root=PARTUUID=df909cde-02 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fsck.repair=yes
 net.ifnames=0 logo.nologo" \
    -no-reboot \
    -serial stdio
```

```
[    0.827340] Initializing XFRM netlink socket 
[    0.827593] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
[    0.828221] Key type dns_resolver registered 
[    0.829502] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.829662] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.830795] Key type ._fscrypt registered
[    0.830908] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    0.830998] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
[    0.834275] of_cfs_init
[    0.835387] of_cfs_init: OK
[    0.843886] uart-pl011 9000000.pl011: no DMA platform data
[    0.846894] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=df909cde-02...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://peterbabic.dev/blog/how-emulate-raspios-natively-qemu/) seems to have the answer. Based on that, I'm able to boot the ARMv8 image like this (after copying `kernel8.img` and `bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb` out of the image):

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -m 1024 \
    -M raspi3 \
    -kernel kernel8.img \
    -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb \
    -drive file=DietPi_RPi-ARMv8-Bullseye.img,format=raw \
    -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4" \
    -device usb-net,netdev=net0 \
    -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
    -serial stdio
```

This boots without a problem, but I'm unable to access the console. However, I can log in using ssh just fine:

```
$ ssh -p 2222 root@localhost
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:2222' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
root@localhost's password:
```

Enter the default password (`dietpi`), and you're all set. DietPi wants to run a bunch of initialization scripts when you first log in, but after that things seem to work as expected.

---

**Update 1**: well, once, until it rebooted. Does dietpi disable ssh after initial configuration? Trying to investigate, but I can't get console access to work at all, so without the network I appear to be SOL.

---

**Update 2***: The problems I was having appear to be entirely due to the "dietpi" image. If I just use the [Raspberry Pi OS 64bit Lite image](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_oldstable_lite_armhf/images/raspios_oldstable_lite_armhf-2022-04-07/2022-04-04-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img.xz), then console access works correctly.

"user" mode networking doesn't seem to survive a reboot, but setting up a tap device works nicely.

This is what I ended up using as my command line:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -M raspi3 \
  -kernel kernel8.img \
  -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4 console=ttyAMA0" \
  -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb \
  -m 1024 \
  -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/raspios-work.img,format=raw \
  -netdev tap,id=net0,script=no,downscript=no,ifname=rpi0 \
  -device usb-net,netdev=net0 \
  -nographic \
  -serial mon:stdio
```